# display the image in the right corner

Tags: android

I have the following code with which i am trying to display at right corner of the title bar but its getting displayed in center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/formheader">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the properties of `RelativeLayout`, So it won't work with `LinearLayout`.

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to `TextView`.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Change it like below :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways,

1. Follow @prag's answer if you want to continue with `LinearLayout`.
2. Another simplest way is to use `RelativeLayout` like below,

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="35dip"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/formheader">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/header"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:text="ShowRoom"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black"
           android:textStyle="bold"/>

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Replace my drawable image with yours. Hope this resolves your problem

Comment: I am stuck with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939576/scrollable-list-of-items-in-a-table-format can you please help me